# Should people who want to study arithmetic geometry study complex geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, arithmetic, complex-geometry

I want to study arithmetic geometry, and I have read some fundamental texts of  algebraic geometry, such as Hartshorne.
Next I'm studying etale cohomology and abelian varieties.
On texts of these theories, the author sometimes takes some pages for complex geometry as a classical theory.
(For example, complex Lie groups as a classical theory of abelian varieties.)
For understanding these example completely, I have to study complex geometry, and for complex geometry, I have to study many analysis.
It takes a lots of time, but I don't know whether it is worthwhile to study complex geometry deeply, for people who want to learn arithmetic, such as me.
And also I don't know whether it is safe to use complex geometry as a black box.

So I wonder if I should study complex geometry, or study arithmetic using complex geometry as a black box.

Comment: As someone in a similar position, it seems to me we want to build it up as and when we need it. Don't spend a semester reading complex geometry and neglecting the arithmetic, but if complex Lie groups arise in what you are studying, it makes sense to build up some background (Chapters 7 onwards in Representation Theory by Fulton + Harris, for instance)

Comment: So many arithmetic concepts come from the complex world, I have been burned many times by not understanding complex geometry better.

Comment: The algorithm is simple: more maths is always better than not enough maths.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
So... Because many ideas of arithmetic comes from complex geometry I should study it. But should not spend too much time. (Learning arithmetic itself is better than learning complex geometry, its background.) Learn it as and when I need.
Right?

Comment: It is often important to understand motivation from complex geometry (e.g. vanishing cycles and Milnor fibres), but I don't think it is important to understand the (often analytic) proofs.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense, as soon as one studies complex geometry, they won't want to study anything else ;)